# Can't determine why sizeof shows different value

Tags: c, concatenation, sizeof

I am making a program that concatenates two strings given by user. Everything is fine, but I  don't know why the program shows that the ***sizeof*** of the final result is 8-bit long. Doesn't matter how long the strings are, it always shows 8. I guess, that it is the size of **char**, but I would like to know why it acts this way. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concatenate(char *fir, char *sec)
{
int firLen = strlen(fir);
int secLen = strlen(sec);
int len = firLen + secLen + 1;
int i = 0,c=0;
int *wsk = &i;

char *result = (char *)malloc(len*sizeof(char));

while (fir[i]!='\0')
{
    result[i]=fir[i];
    (*wsk)++;
}

while (sec[c]!='\0')
{
    result[i]=sec[c];
    (*wsk)++;
    c++;
}

result[len-1] = '\0';
return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char *first, *second, *output;
int size1, size2;

printf("How long will your first string be: ");
scanf("%d", &size1);

first = (char *) malloc ((1+size1)*sizeof(char));
if (!first)
{
    puts("\nError. Can't allocate memory!");
    abort();
}

printf("How long will your second string be: ");
scanf("%d", &size2);

second = (char *) malloc ((size2+1)*sizeof(char));
if (!second)
{
    puts("\nError. Can't allocate memory!");
    abort();
}

printf("\nPlease, type in the first string: ");
scanf("%s",first);

printf("\nPlease, type in the second string: ");
scanf("%s",second);

output = (char *)malloc((size1+size2+1)*sizeof(char));
output = concatenate(first, second);

printf("\nConcatenation of the strings: %s", output);
printf("\n%d", sizeof(output));

free(first);
free(second);
free(output);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C standard, so there's no need to multiply things by `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: `sizeof()` shows an answer in *bytes*, not *bits*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `sizeof` to determine *string length*, use the `strlen` function, as you're doing in other parts of your program.

```
printf("\nConcatenation of the strings: %s", output);
printf("\n%d", strlen(output));
```

Use `sizeof` to determine the size of *data types*, like `char`, a `struct`, an array, etc.

You've mentioned that you want to use `sizeof` to *check if everything is fine with memory allocation*, but you can't use `sizeof` this way on a buffer of memory allocated with `malloc`: you can only rely on the return value of `malloc` - which you aren't checking - to know if your allocation was successful.

You *can* use `sizeof` to determine the size of an array:

```
char myStr[13];
printf("%d\n", sizeof(myStr));
```

But this only works for arrays, and not buffers allocated using `malloc`.

Also this line creates a memory leak because you overwrite the pointer in the next line:

```
output = (char *)malloc((size1+size2+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: I know the differences between strlen and sizeof, but using sizeof(output) I wanted to check if everything is fine with memory allocation.

Comment: @mic4ael: That's not possible in C. There is no way to ask a pointer to how much memory it points to.

Comment: @mic4ael you can only rely on the return value of `malloc` for that

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` gives the size in *bytes*, where a byte is the size of a `char`.

```
printf("\n%d", sizeof(output));
```

`output` is a `char*`, so on your system `char*`s are 8 bytes large. You must use `strlen` to obtain the length of a 0-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("\n%d", sizeof(output));` prints a size of pointer to `char`. You platform appears to have pointers that are 8 bytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
second = (char *) malloc ((size2+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Don't typecast the result of `malloc()`.

Second: 
`sizeof(char)` is going to be 1, a char is 1 byte and `sizeof()` returns the number of bytes required to hold that data type. So you don't need the `*sizeof(char)`, you need that for larger types like `int`.

Finally:

```
printf("\nConcatenation of the strings: %s", output);    printf("\n%d", sizeof(output));
```

`output` is a `char *` so this is going to give you the `sizeof(char *)` on your system.

You said in a previous comment:
`I know the differences between strlen and sizeof, but using sizeof(output) I wanted to check if everything is fine with memory allocation`

Sounds like what you wanted was to verify that you allocated the correct amount of memory for the two concatenated strings. `sizeof()` won't give you that information. It's in the low level details at this point, you need to do something OS dependent to try and find that information. (ex. in the linux kernel if you `kmalloc()` memory you can use `ksize()` to find out exactly how many bytes you got)

Comment: @mic4ael - Also true, but I was assuming you wanted to get that programmatically